# How do I display the most frequent number in an array filled with random numbers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a lottery game where a user inputs 10 numbers and then plays the same 10 numbers every day for a year. I generate 365 random numbers which simulates one new number for each day of the year. I need help with case 4 in my menu. How do I go about displaying which of the 365 random numbers showed up the most?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define SIZE 365
#define FLUSH fflush(stdin)
#define CLS system("cls")
#define LB 0
#define UB 999



main(){

    int userInput = 0;
    int userNumber = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int userNumbers[9] = { 0 };
    int i;
    int j;
    int f;
    int winningNumbers[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int moneySpent = 3600;
    int moneyEarned = 0;
    int profitMade = 0;
    int timesWon = 0;
    int matchingNumbers[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int userNumberOne = 0;
    int userNumberTwo = 0;
    int userNumberThree = 0;
    int userNumberFour = 0;
    int userNumberFive = 0;
    int userNumberSix = 0;
    int userNumberSeven = 0;
    int userNumberEight = 0;
    int userNumberNine = 0;
    int userNumberTen = 0;
    int a = 0;



    do {

        // Display Menu
        CLS;
        printf("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n");
        printf("$$                         $$\n");
        printf("$$    THE LOTTERY GAME     $$\n");
        printf("$$                         $$\n");
        printf("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n\n\n");



        printf("1. Enter your 10 lottery numbers. \n");
        printf("2. Play the lottery. \n");
        printf("3. Display summary of your 10 numbers. \n");
        printf("4. Display most repeated number. \n");
        printf("5. QUIT \n");
        printf("\n\nEnter your selection: ");

        // Get User Choice
        scanf("%i", &userInput);



        CLS;


        //Write the Switch
        switch (userInput){

            srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); // Seeds the rand function

        case 1:   // User inputs 10 lottery numbers to play




            for (count; count < 10; count++) { //Loops 10 times



                    printf("\nEnter #%i of 10 for your lottery numbers [BETWEEN 0 - 999]: ", count + 1); // Tells user to input 10 numbers
                    scanf("%i", &userNumber); // Gets users' 10 lottery numbers

                    userNumbers[count] = userNumber; // Stores the users' lottery numbers into an array

            } // End for loop



            PAUSE;
            break;
        case 2:   // Plays the lottery
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

                winningNumbers[i] = LB + rand() % (UB - LB + 1);  // Generates 365 random lottery numbers

            } // End for loop

            for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

                if (userNumbers[0] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[0];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberOne++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[1] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[1];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberTwo++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[2] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[2];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberThree++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[3] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[3];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberFour++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[4] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[4];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberFive++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[5] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[5];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberSix++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[6] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[6];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberSeven++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[7] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[7];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberEight++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[8] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[8];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberNine++;
                }
                else if (userNumbers[9] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                    matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[9];
                    timesWon++;
                    userNumberTen++;
                }
            } // End for loop 

            printf("You WON the lottery %i times!\n\n", timesWon);

            printf("Your winning numbers are: \n");
            for (f = 0; f < timesWon; f++){


                printf("%i \n", matchingNumbers[f]);

            } // End for loop

            moneyEarned = 500 * timesWon;
            profitMade = moneyEarned - moneySpent;


            printf("\n\n");
            printf("You WON $%i total!\n", moneyEarned);
            printf("You spent $%i total.\n", moneySpent);
            printf("Your profit is $%i! \n\n", profitMade);


            PAUSE;
            break;
        case 3:  // Displays summary of the user's 10 numbers
            printf("$$$$ Your lottery number summary $$$$\n\n");
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[0], userNumberOne);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[1], userNumberTwo);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[2], userNumberThree);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[3], userNumberFour);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[4], userNumberFive);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[5], userNumberSix);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[6], userNumberSeven);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[7], userNumberEight);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[8], userNumberNine);
            printf("Lottery number %i won %i times.\n\n\n", userNumbers[9], userNumberTen);

            PAUSE;
            break;
        case 4: // Displays most repeated number


            PAUSE;
            break;
        case 5:  // QUIT
            printf("Thank you for playing the lottery game!\n\n");

            break;


        }//End Switch



    } while (userInput != 5);








    PAUSE;

} // End main
```

Comment: I didn't go through your source code. But if you want to identify the number which has used the most. You need to somehow manage a data structure that refer to the no of count of each number(365 numbers). If your numbers are fixed..say 1-365 then you can use a size_t count_array of 365 elements. and each time when getting a number just increase the counr_array[number]++. Or you can implement a max heap.

Comment: you want to display "most repeated number" but in where? Do you mean within the generated random number?

Comment: Be aware `fflush(stdin)` does not do what you think it does. In general `fflush` only applies to *output* streams, and will not remove the dangling newline from `stdin`.

Answer (score 2):

This works, please read // NOTE in the code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define SIZE 365
#define FLUSH fflush(stdin)
#define CLS system("cls")
#define LB 0
#define UB 999

int main(  )
{
  int userInput = 0;
  int userNumber = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int userNumbers[9 + 1] = { 0 };
  int i;
  int j;
  int f;
  int winningNumbers[SIZE] = { 0 };
  int moneySpent = 3600;
  int moneyEarned = 0;
  int profitMade = 0;
  int timesWon = 0;
  int matchingNumbers[SIZE] = { 0 };
  int userNumberOne = 0;
  int userNumberTwo = 0;
  int userNumberThree = 0;
  int userNumberFour = 0;
  int userNumberFive = 0;
  int userNumberSix = 0;
  int userNumberSeven = 0;
  int userNumberEight = 0;
  int userNumberNine = 0;
  int userNumberTen = 0;
  int a = 0;
 // NOTE +1 needed below
  int lotnum[UB + 1] = { 0 };
 // NOTE some new variables here
  int most_repeated = 0;
  int tempint = 0;

  do
  {
    // Display Menu
    CLS;
    printf( "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n" );
    printf( "$$                         $$\n" );
    printf( "$$    THE LOTTERY GAME     $$\n" );
    printf( "$$                         $$\n" );
    printf( "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n\n\n" );
    printf( "1. Enter your 10 lottery numbers. \n" );
    printf( "2. Play the lottery. \n" );
    printf( "3. Display summary of your 10 numbers. \n" );
    printf( "4. Display most repeated number. \n" );
    printf( "5. QUIT \n" );
    printf( "\n\nEnter your selection: " );
    // Get User Choice
    scanf( "%i", &userInput );
    CLS;

    srand( ( unsigned ) time( NULL ) ); // Seeds the rand function

    //Write the Switch
    switch ( userInput )
    {

    case 1:         // User inputs 10 lottery numbers to play
      for ( count; count < 10; count++ )
      {             //Loops 10 times
    printf( "\nEnter #%i of 10 for your lottery numbers [BETWEEN 0 - 999]: ", count + 1 );  // Tells u    ser to input 10 numbers
    scanf( "%i", &userNumber ); // Gets users' 10 lottery numbers
    userNumbers[count] = userNumber;    // Stores the users' lottery numbers into an array
      }             // End for loop
      PAUSE;
      break;
    case 2:         // Plays the lottery

      for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
      {
    winningNumbers[i] = LB + rand(  ) % ( UB - LB + 1 );    // Generates 365 random lottery numbers
    printf( "\nwN==%d", winningNumbers[i] );

      }             // End for loop
      for ( j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
      {
    if ( userNumbers[0] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[0];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberOne++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[1] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[1];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberTwo++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[2] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[2];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberThree++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[3] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[3];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberFour++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[4] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[4];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberFive++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[5] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[5];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberSix++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[6] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[6];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberSeven++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[7] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[7];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberEight++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[8] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[8];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberNine++;
    }
    else if ( userNumbers[9] == winningNumbers[j] )
    {
      matchingNumbers[timesWon] = userNumbers[9];
      timesWon++;
      userNumberTen++;
    }
      }             // End for loop
      printf( "You WON the lottery %i times!\n\n", timesWon );
      printf( "Your winning numbers are: \n" );
      for ( f = 0; f < timesWon; f++ )
      {
    printf( "%i \n", matchingNumbers[f] );
      }             // End for loop
      moneyEarned = 500 * timesWon;
      profitMade = moneyEarned - moneySpent;
      printf( "\n\n" );
      printf( "You WON $%i total!\n", moneyEarned );
      printf( "You spent $%i total.\n", moneySpent );
      printf( "Your profit is $%i! \n\n", profitMade );
      PAUSE;
      break;
    case 3:         // Displays summary of the user's 10 numbers
      printf( "$$$$ Your lottery number summary $$$$\n\n" );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[0],
          userNumberOne );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[1],
          userNumberTwo );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[2],
          userNumberThree );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[3],
          userNumberFour );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[4],
          userNumberFive );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[5],
          userNumberSix );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[6],
          userNumberSeven );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[7],
          userNumberEight );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n", userNumbers[8],
          userNumberNine );
      printf( "Lottery number %i won %i times.\n\n\n", userNumbers[9],
          userNumberTen );
      PAUSE;
      break;

    case 4:         // Displays most repeated number

      for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
      {
    tempint = winningNumbers[i]; // NOTE could be shorter, but this is easier to read
    lotnum[tempint]++;

    printf( "\n lotnum[%d]==%d", tempint, lotnum[tempint] );  // NOTE switch off this line after you understand it
      }
      most_repeated = 0;
      for ( i = 0; i < UB; i++ )
         if ( lotnum[i] > most_repeated )
            most_repeated = i;

      printf( "\nMost repeated number==%d\n", most_repeated );
      // NOTE : you could have multiple numbers with same score

      PAUSE;
      break;
    case 5:         // QUIT
      printf( "Thank you for playing the lottery game!\n\n" );
      break;
    }               //End Switch
  }
  while ( userInput != 5 );
  PAUSE;

}               // End main
```